# Reduce Percentage from Date-Time in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, joomla

```
$order_created = date('d.m.Y H:i:s',$items[0]->created2);
                        $order_deadline = date('d.m.Y H:i:s',$items[0]->created);
                        $order_created = new DateTime($order_created);
                        $order_deadline = new DateTime($order_deadline);
                        $interval = $order_created->diff($order_deadline);
                        echo $interval->format('%d days %H hours %i minutes')?>;"
```

Now I want to reduce 30% from the $interval i.e. the date-time being displayed at the end.

For e.g. if the deadline is 10th july after 30% reduction it should display as 7th July along with time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the difference between the two dates as a timestamp, and then subtract the 30% to create a new `DateTime` that can then be compared to the order_created.

#### Example

```
$order_created = new DateTime("29-07-2016");
$order_deadline = new DateTime("30-07-2016");

//Get the difference in seconds between the two DateTimes
$diff = $order_created->getTimestamp() - $order_deadline->getTimestamp();

//Subtract 30%
$diff = $diff * 0.70;

//Create the new deadline (@ is used to initialize a DateTime with a Timestamp)
$new_deadline = new DateTime('@' . ($order_deadline->getTimeStamp() - $diff));

$result = $order_created->diff($new_deadline);
```